# Issues with creating an animation using matplotlib for normal, gaussian, exponential and gamma distributions

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, animation, visualization

I have the following code below to create an animation for a Gaussian, Normal, Exponential and Gamma distribution:

```
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
fig = plt.figure()

def update(curr):
        if curr == n: 
            a.event_source.stop()
        plt.cla()
        plt.axis([-7,21,0,0.6])
        bins = np.arange(-7,21,1)
        plt.hist(x[:curr], bins=bins)
        plt.gca().set_title('Sampling the' + " "+distribution+" " + 'Distribution')
        plt.gca().set_ylabel('Frequency')
        plt.gca().set_xlabel('Value')
        plt.annotate('n = {}'.format(curr), [3,27])

n = 10000
x = np.random.normal(-2.5, 1, 10000)
distribution = 'normal'
a1 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=100)
x = np.random.gamma(2, 1.5, 10000)
distribution = 'gamma'
a2 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=100)
x = np.random.exponential(2, 10000)+7
distribution = 'exponential'
a3 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=100)
x = np.random.uniform(14,20, 10000)
distribution = 'uniform'
a4 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=100)
```

I want to create 4 animations, one of a normal distribution, one of a Gaussian distribution, one of an exponential distribution and one of a gamma distribution.

However, when I run this code I get a blank graph (with only the y-axis and x-axis).

Could anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Why do you re-define the `update()` function 4 different times? Then, you want the 4 animations in 4 different subplots or overlapped in the same `ax`?

Comment: @AndreaBlengino 4 animations in 4 different subplots, and yes have edited the post above

Comment: Ok, and what would you like to see in the animation? What property has to change frame by frame as the animation goes on?

Comment: pulling between 100 and 1000 samples from each of the random variables (x1, x2, x3, x4) for each plot and plotting this @AndreaBlengino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rearranged your code a little bit to make the animation work properly.
The animation is updated in the `animate()` function, instead I use the `plot_histogram()` function to avoid repetitions.
The parameter that is updated frame by frame is `i`, which in this case is used to increase the number of samples from which the `np.random._` functions draw.

```
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize = (8, 8))
bins = np.arange(-7,21,1)

def animate(i):
        normal_data = np.random.normal(-2.5, 1, 100*i)
        plot_histogram(ax[0, 0], normal_data, 'Sampling the Normal Distribution', 'n = {}'.format(100*i))

        gamma_data = np.random.gamma(2, 1.5, 100*i)
        plot_histogram(ax[0, 1], gamma_data, 'Sampling the Gamma Distribution', 'n = {}'.format(100*i))

        exponential_data = np.random.exponential(2, 100*i)+7
        plot_histogram(ax[1, 0], exponential_data, 'Sampling the Exponential Distribution', 'n = {}'.format(100*i))

        uniform_data = np.random.uniform(14,20, 100*i)
        plot_histogram(ax[1, 1], uniform_data, 'Sampling the Uniform Distribution', 'n = {}'.format(100*i))

def plot_histogram(ax, data, title, annotation):
    ax.cla()
    ax.hist(data, bins = bins)
    ax.set_title(title)
    ax.set_ylabel('Frequency')
    ax.set_xlabel('Value')
    ax.annotate(annotation, [3, 27])

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames = 11, interval = 200)

plt.show()
```

With this code I get this animation:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, the 100*i, means you draw out 100 values for each plot in the animation?

Comment: and when you call 'animate' in the line 'ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames = 11, interval = 200)', you don't need to insert any value for 'i', because i automatically means on each frame/round?

Comment: and why did my first formula not actually work? What was it about it that needed changing? The use of plot_histogram?

Comment: `i` goes automatically from 1 to the specified number of frames. I multiply it by 100 in order to start from 100 samples. At the end of the animation `i` is set to 10 (in the last performed loop), so the samples in this last case are 1000. In your first formula the counter (`i` for me) is `curr`: in your code `curr` does not change the number of samples of the `np.random._` functions

Comment: and i is set to 10 and not to 11 because it automatically finishes at the number of frames - 1?

Comment: Exactly, like every cycle in Python, the final limit is exclusive. As in `for i in range (0, 10)`, the `i` goes from `0` to `9`

Comment: thank you so much for your help, I have learnt python from scratch during lockdown and at times it can be really fustrating!! sorry to bother you